# How to override class variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, activemerchant, shopify-activemerchant

I'm trying to override the 'requires_name' method or its variable on line 315 of https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/credit_card.rb so that the check on line 328 is not performed. In Australia, the card name is not normally collected during payment so I'm trying to pass in nils. I have not gotten anything to work.

I've tried class_variable_set like:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.class_variable_set(:@@requires_name, Proc.new do
    false
end)
```

I've tried requires_name and require_name here. No difference.

I've tried:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.requires_name = Proc.new do
    false
end)
```

I've tried various other things. How do I override it?

Comment: Try `ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.require_name = false`

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. It was that simple! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override the method, but it's easier to set the value the method is returning:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.require_name = false
```

Internally, `require_name` is stored as a **class instance variable**:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.instance_variable_get(:@require_name)
#=> false
```